# Using jQuery's live() with a selector containing next()

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-selectors, bind

I do use jQuery live() to bind a 'click' event to certain images. This results in the following internal live-selector:

```
#tblViews tbody tr[rel=view_4].next() table.editable.includes span.actions img.remove
```

When I click on such an image, the following error occurs:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

I think the problem might be the .next() in the selector - but how to get rid of that?

Thanks a lot,
Remo

Answer (score 1):

It does say in the documentation the 'live' cannot be used like that.  you need to have a complete

```
$('selector').live( function(){});
```

For example,

```
$('select1').next('select2').live(...);
```

will not work.

I'm going to assume you're using the .next() because you want the second matching tr.  In this case I suggest using tr[rel=view_4]:eq(1) in the selector instead.

If you provide the code you use to bind the live event I should be able to write a version that will work correctly with jquery live.

Have fun :)